# Holomorphic functions $f,g$ s.t. $f = \lambda g$ with $|\lambda| = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Let $D,U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be non-empty domains s.t. $\overline{D} \subseteq U$ with compact $\overline{D}$. Assume $f,g$ are holomorphic on $U$. If $f,g$ have no zeros in $\overline{D}$ and $|f(z)| = |g(z)|$ for $z \in \partial{D}$ then there exists a $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $|\lambda| = 1$ and $f = \lambda g$.

I started like this: Consider $h := \frac{f|_{\overline{D}}}{g|_{\overline{D}}}$. Because $g$ has no zeros $h$ is holomorphic on $\overline{D}$. Since $\overline{D}$ is compact and $|h(z)| = 1$ for $z \in \partial{D}$ by the maximum principle, we get $h(\overline{D}) \subseteq U_1(0)$. How should I continue?

Comment: As you say, you need to use maximum modulus principle. Since $h(z)$ attains its maximum modulus in the interior of $D$, it must be constant.

Comment: You also can consider $g/f$.

Comment: Oh you're right, I totally missed that! Ok, so $h(z) = \lambda$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and since $|h(z)| = 1$ for $z \in \partial{D}$ we have $|\lambda| = 1$?

Comment: @daruma Why does $|h|$ attain $1$ in the interior of $D$?